# Get <select> data from for result

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get data from for operation result, and put in `<select>` element. But I am not able to do that

```
let time;

  for (time = 0; time < 24; time++) {
    if (time < 10) {
      console.log('0' + time + '.00');
    } else {
      console.log(time + '.00');
    }
  }
```

I want the result like

```
<option> time </option>
```

Comment: What have you tried for this? What research have you done? What is your issue?

Comment: this is puzzling: `let a;`

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: So, you want to populate a selectbox with values from an array?

Comment: @StefanN from a for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
let options = '';
for (let i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
    if (i < 10) {
        let time = "0" + i + ".00"
        options += '<option value="' + time + '">' + time + '</option>'
    } else {
        let time = i + ".00"
        options += '<option value="' + time + '">' + time + '</option>'
    }
}
document.getElementById('timeOptions').innerHTML = options;
```

and in your body, do this:

`<select id="timeOptions"></select>`

Comment: it said Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: it's working now. i have made some corrections. please accept the answer if it worked for you

Comment: its work, but I try to put in 2 selector, but the another doesn't load it

Comment: share your code or open another question, i will help you again